# array of cylinders around sphere surface (sea-urchin-like)

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have a sphere and I want to make some cylindrical cavities on it's surface, which are tangent to the sphere's surface
The cylinders wich which I should make the boolean difference should be disposed as a sea urchin, i suppose: with the bottom faces of the cylinders being on the same origin and the top faces spreading out radially.

Here are some images to give a better idea of what I should do:

This is a "flattened" version of what I want to acieve
[image]

How do I do the same thing on a sphere?

I need to get to the point where i get something like this but with the cylinders going all around the sphere orbiting around its Z-axis

[image]

Thanks in advance :D

Edit: Is there a versatile way of doing so on objects which have an elliptical/irregular shape?

Comment: Thanks @zeffii , is there a more general approach towards a non spherical/round object?

What if the sphere were "squashed" on one axis and I wanted the cylinders to rotate around that axis (therefore performing an elliptical revolution)?

Comment: Yeah, you might use Duplifaces, but that becomes a different Question entirely, with different approaches.

Comment: k, posting a new question then, thanks :)